# how can I go about using the Gemfile's :path argument to reference local gems in development with a value that is OS agnostic?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I am writing a Gemfile to help with the development of a few gems my team is creating.

I know that the Gemfile allows the use of the :path argument to reference local directories that contain a .gemspec file:

gem "my_gem", :path => "../Ruby_Libs/my_gem"

However, the members of my team are using different OSs (OS X, Win XP, Win 7) when writing their code.

So my question is how can I go about using the Gemfile's :path argument to reference local gems in development with a value that is OS agnostic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `File.join('..', 'Ruby_Libs', 'my_gem'')` instead of `"../Ruby_Libs/my_gem"`.

```
gem "my_gem", :path => File.join('..', 'Ruby_Libs', 'my_gem'')
```

Comment: Awesome, I figured that was the answer, but wasn't sure if I could use Ruby inside of a gem file.

Comment: A Gemfile is all Ruby!

Comment: where in the *.gemspec file do we write the gem and path to join file? 
Then how do we install it from a different location?